# Ionic - Routing to a view that was already loaded gets blank page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic, and i have a  with  in it, and im using   to navigate between my views.

this is my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ui.router']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory       bar above the keyboard
  // for form inputs)
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

  // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
  // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
  // a much nicer keyboard experience.
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

// Sign in - Initial display
$stateProvider.state('sign_in', {
    url: '/signIn',
    templateUrl: 'html/signIn.html',
    controller: 'signInController' 
})

.state('sign_up', {
    url: '/signUp',
    templateUrl: 'html/signUp.html',
    controller: 'signUpController'
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/signIn');
});
```

My default view is '/signIn'. when i navigate to '/signUp' everything is fine. But when i use the back button to go back to '/signIn' the content of the '/signIn' view appears for a milisec and then disappears and i get blank page.

Some conclutions:

1. I can see the elements borders in the developer tools.
2. It happens only when i navigate to a view that was already loaded.
3. When i resize the browser in any kind of way (minimize, changing
   device, resolution etc...) the view appears as it should.
4. It also happens when i use 'state.go(/signIn)' to navigate back to the
   '/signIn' page.

Please help me im really lost with this thing...
btw, is this the 'white screen of death'?

Comment: anything in the browser error logs?

Comment: nothing in the error log